# Specifying system properties in Grails 2.0 interactive mode

Tags: grails, system-properties, grails-2.0, interactive-mode

Is there a way how to specify system property in (already started) grails interactive mode ?

For example I would specify environment in command line:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=staging run-app
```

but in interactive mode it is not possible this way (since JVM is already started):

```
grails
grails> -Dgrails.env=staging run-app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work in Grails 1.3.7 interactive mode.  Add a script to your Grails application at `scripts/SetProperty.groovy`:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript('_GrailsArgParsing')

target (default:'Set a system property') {
    depends('parseArguments')
    if (argsMap['params'][0] && argsMap['params'][1]) {
        System.setProperty(argsMap['params'][0], argsMap['params'][1])
    } else {
        println 'You must define a property to set'
    }
}
```

Then in interactive mode `set-property grails.env staging`.

Comment: Nice. I can confirm this "workaround" also works in Grails 2.0.0.M2. Thanks.